# Multithreading in jsp

Tags: jsp

I have been using jsp and servlets for quite long time. But i have not come across multi threading . Is it possible. If so please can some one suggest me some sample program please

Answer (score 0):

JSP bits are actually compiled to servlets and they are multi-threaded anyway and. Servlets are believed to be thread-safe. You may use the page directive <%@ page isThreadSafe="false" %> in case your JSP is not thread safe, in this way  the container uses a single threaded execution of the resulting servlet. In this case the container may create multiple instances of the JSP servlet to handle concurrent requests or use synchronization to control access to a single instance. Please be cautious that, It may affect the performance of the page due to the overheads of instantiation and locking.

Comment: Servlets are not 'believed to be thread safe'. They must be *written* so as to be thread-safe, i.e. no instance variables that relate to a single request or session. Do you mean '*assumed* to be thread-safe'?